# How to use Paypal Checkout Hosted pages for Credit Card payments in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am facing problem in implementing Credit Card payments using Paypal Checkout Hosted pages for Credit Card transactions.

This is my code for Paypal payments:

```
public ActionResult CreatePayment(string packageName)
    {
        #region check client balance
        long clientid = Convert.ToInt64(Session["iClientId"]);
        string newPaymentMethod = "PayPal";
        ClientPackageInfo obj = new ClientPackageInfo();
        obj = objPaymentHelper.CalculateNewPackage(packageName, clientid, newPaymentMethod);

        #region current package descriptor for paypal display
        var newPkg = db.Package.Where(cs => cs.PackageId == obj.newPackageId).SingleOrDefault();
        string paypalDisplayDecription = "Package : "+newPkg.Name+", Price : "+newPkg.Price+", Payable : "+obj.paymentAmount+", Description : "+newPkg.Description;
        #endregion

        if (obj.IsPaymentNeeded == true)
        {

            #region paypal viewdata
            var viewData = new PayPalViewData();
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var paymentInit = new PayPal.Api.Payments.Payment
            {
                intent = "authorize",
                payer = new PayPal.Api.Payments.Payer
                {
                    payment_method = "paypal"
                },
                transactions = new List<PayPal.Api.Payments.Transaction>
            {
                new PayPal.Api.Payments.Transaction
                {
                    amount = new PayPal.Api.Payments.Amount
                    {
                        currency = "USD",
                        total = (obj.paymentAmount + 0.0 + 0.0).ToString(),
                        details = new PayPal.Api.Payments.Details
                        {
                            subtotal = obj.paymentAmount.ToString(),
                            tax = 0.0.ToString(),
                            shipping = 0.0.ToString()
                        }
                    },
                    description = paypalDisplayDecription,
                },
            },
                redirect_urls = new PayPal.Api.Payments.RedirectUrls
                {
                    return_url = Utilities.ToAbsoluteUrl(HttpContext, String.Format("~/payment/confirmed?id={0}", guid)),
                    cancel_url = Utilities.ToAbsoluteUrl(HttpContext, String.Format("~/payment/index?id={0}", guid)),
                },
            };

            viewData.JsonRequest = JObject.Parse(paymentInit.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            #endregion

            #region create payment
            try
            {
                var abc = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties()["ClientID"];
                var abcc = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties()["ClientSecret"];
                var accessToken = new PayPal.OAuthTokenCredential(ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties()["ClientID"], ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties()["ClientSecret"]).GetAccessToken();
                var apiContext = new PayPal.APIContext(accessToken);
                var createdPayment = paymentInit.Create(apiContext);

                var approvalUrl = createdPayment.links.ToArray().FirstOrDefault(f => f.rel.Contains("approval_url"));

                if (approvalUrl != null)
                {
                    Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);

                    return Redirect(approvalUrl.href);
                }

                viewData.JsonResponse = JObject.Parse(createdPayment.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

                return View("Error", viewData);
            }
            catch (PayPalException ex)
            {
                viewData.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                return View("Error", viewData);
            }
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            #region save client information
            SaveClientInfo saveinfo = new SaveClientInfo();
            saveinfo = objPaymentHelper.SaveInfo(obj);
            if(saveinfo.isSuccessfull == true)
            {
                Session["message"] = "show";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "iClientPackageHistory");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            #endregion
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

I am not able to find a way to use the Checkout hosted pages of Paypal. I have already generated the code snippet of Paypal to be used on my page. Kindly help me how can I make changes to this code to be able to use Paypal Checkout Hosted Pages using C# MVC.

Comment: I do not see anywhere in your code wherein you make a call to PayPal. You create the packet to send it to PayPal but I do not see you sending it.

Comment: I agree with @CodingYoshi you never call the PayPal service. It's like this, you write a letter, put it in the envelope. That's your code. The problem is there is no address to send it to. So the envelope(your code) is just sitting there. Make a call to PayPal so your service request can send the packets, then also receive the results... Sorry for the envelope analogy. I wanted to try it on SO.

Comment: I think you have not much knowledge of PayPal implementations and just commenting here, this is the code that makes call and redirects me to Paypal Page for transactions using Paypal Account: 
return Redirect(approvalUrl.href);